# Maximum number of edges in a Line Graph L(G)

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, extremal-graph-theory

The line graph () of a simple graph  is defined as follows:

There is exactly one vertex () in () for each edge  in .

That being said, how can I prove that the maximum number of edges in L(G) is:
$$\frac{n^3 - 3n^2 + 2n}{2}$$

where n is the number of vertices of G.

It would be amazing to have a detailed explanation, since I am not the brightest when it comes to proofs, but tips are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a part of the definition of L(G). An edge in L(G) is generated with endpoints v(e) and v(f) when e and f share a vertex in G.

Thus you can associate each edge in L(G) with a unique vertex in G, and if the vertex has degree $n-1$ there are ${n-1\choose 2}$ such edges (picking any pair of edges).

But as we have $n$ vertices and a simple graph, each vertex has degree $n-1$ at most and thus the number of edges in L(G) is bounded by $n{n-1 \choose 2} = \frac{n^3 - 3n^2 + 2n}{2}$

Comment: So simple! thanks a lot!